# Jupyter notebooks not formatted as usual anymore in github

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook, format

Anyone understand why, on github, my notebook used to look like this :

[image]

And now it looks like this :

[image]

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but you can view notebooks with https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/ as well

Comment: Yeah I know nbviewer, thks